# How to implement mobile data loss prevention (DLP) tools?

Tags: security, mobile, google-cloud-dlp

How to implement mobile data loss prevention (DLP) tools? I have googled but unable to gather the information. Anybody has documentation or life-cycle, flow of Mobile DLP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you are looking for a tool that will give you information about Data leakage goes out from your mobile device through apps like Dropbox,google,Trello etc .., We released yesterday a project called SecuriGo to give viability about application of data in more than 100 apps, take a look at www.securigo.com